# Why don’t we have to toivel hot water heaters?

Tags: halacha, tevilas-keilim-dipping

If a water heater is essentially a giant pot why is it different than a coffee urn which does the same thing but is required to be toiveled?

Comment: Could you add information on why we don't have to toivel a hot water heater? Did you see this somewhere? Heard it from someone?

Comment: I never drink hot water from the tap. It's used for bathing and dishwashing. Why would it need Tevila?

Comment: I remember hearing the following regarding a commercial water urn. It's mechuber lkarka through the piping. It is assembled after the jew owns it.

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2008/01/29/health/29real.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The water heater is connected to the ground by the plumbing (mahuber l'karka) and possibly, bolted down as well.